# Unable to call ViewModel method from activity

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I'm trying to call a method which is in viewModel from activity, but the method is not called.

`LoginViewModel`

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var mLoginData: MutableLiveData<LoginModal>? = null
    private var loginRepository: LoginRepository? = null

    fun initLogin(jsonObject: JsonObject) {
        if (mLoginData != null) {
            return
        }
        loginRepository = LoginRepository().getInstance()
        mLoginData = loginRepository?.getLoginData(jsonObject)
    }

    fun getLoginData(): MutableLiveData<LoginModal>? {
        return mLoginData
    }
}
```

`LoginActivity`

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var etUsername: EditText? = null
    var etPassword: EditText? = null

    var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel? = null
    private var mLoginData: MutableLiveData<LoginModal>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary);

        etUsername = findViewById(R.id.et_username)
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.et_password)

        loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)

    }

    fun login(view: View) {
        val jsonObject = JsonObject()
        jsonObject.addProperty("userId", etUsername!!.text.toString())
        jsonObject.addProperty("password", etPassword!!.text.toString())
        jsonObject.addProperty("deviceId", "45684")

        loginViewModel?.initLogin(jsonObject)

        Log.d("Login Activity", "Login Data : " + mLoginData)
    }
}
```

`login` method is called `onClick` of a button, but `initLogin` is not called.

Please help. Thank You

UPDATE :

`XML` for where `login` is called..

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_login"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="login"/>
```

Comment: Does the log  `Log.d("Login Activity", "Login Data : " + mLoginData)` inside `login` print?

Comment: Have you debug the code?

Comment: Yes I have debugged it, `mLoginData` is defined in `LoginActivity`, removed it by mistake. I will edit the question

Comment: post your xml file

Comment: Please clear about `mLoginData`. You add it both in `Activity` and `ViewModel`. Doesn't get it purpose

Comment: I was just trying to do this `mLoginData = loginViewModel!!.getLoginData()` in `login` method of `LoginActivity`, but as `initLogin` is not called, so while debugging, I removed it.

Comment: First Rebuild the project and if not working, then `File -> Cache/Restart` , it's normal bug sometimes this happens and if still doesn't work just separate your logic you're saying about  `getLoginData()` and `initLogin()`, simply post both method and mention which one is working and which one is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
        1. XML-
          <ImageButton
                   android:layout_width="80dp"
                   android:layout_height="80dp"
                   android:src="@drawable/ic_more"
                   android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                   android:onClick="login"/>
        2. Activity-
            lateinit var viewModel: LoginViewModel
            override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

         viewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)

            }

            fun login(view: View) {
                Log.d("Activity:", "login method called")
                viewModel.initLogin()
            }

    3. View Model 
    fun initLogin() {
            Log.d("Login View model:", "init Login called")
        }
```

I have created sample referring the above problem. But it worked fine for me.Please refer my sample code.

Answer (score 0):

try code:

```
 <data>
<veriable name="login" type="com.example.databinding.Login"/>
</data>
    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_login"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:onClick="@{login}"/>
```

Comment: Please indicate the problem with solution. Do you understand what is the problem?

Comment: My friend onClick is already working. Please read the question once again.